# Failure using CSS background image as border

Tags: css, html, background, border

I'm trying to place an image inside a fancy border such that the border overlays the image.  I've got it ALMOST working, and I'm hopeful someone can give me the last little bit that I need.  In the sample below, if I remove the background from the main div container, the image framing works great.  With the background, the image is invisible, presumably hidden behind the white container background.  Here's a dabblat for testing: http://dabblet.com/gist/4356232

```
<style>
div {
    background: #fff;
}
a {
    width: 287px;
    height: 142px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://divisioncamera.erentalpro.com/web/list.png) no-repeat;

}
img {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 287px;
    max-width: 142px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
<div>
    <a>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `div`

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Genius!  I knew it would be simple, and yet it was forever out of my grasp.  Thanks!